# Problem involving probability and prime numbers.

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, conditional-probability

A 2n digit number starts with 2 and all its digits are prime, then find the probability that the sum of all 2 consecutive digits of the number is prime?
The digits of the prime number are from {2,3,5,7} and the sum of consecutive digits will be prime if the number is something like 2325...but I cannot figure out how to satisfy the condition of the entire number being prime. Please help.

Comment: What does "the sum of all 2 consecutive digits of the number" mean?  For $2325$, what sum do you compute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am inferring correctly your question, the digits will have to have the following pattern 
$$\underbrace{2,\,(5\text{ or }3)}_{\text{pair 1}},\underbrace{\,2,\,(5\text{ or }3)}_{\text{pair 2}},\dots,\,\underbrace{2,\,(5\text{ or }3)}_{\text{pair n}}.$$ I think this gives a probability of $\displaystyle \frac12\left(\frac18\right)^{n-1}$ assuming that the distribution on $\{2,3,5,7\}$ is uniform.

Comment: the digit 7 is never used. oh and last digit can't be 5.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee we can't use 7 because put beside a 2 you get $2+7=9$, which is non-prime. The number itself need not be prime (if I am inferring correctly).

Comment: @JPMcCarthy the pattern is okay but the question also gives the condi that the overall number should be prime. How do we satisfy that?

Comment: Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Yes absolutely...

Comment: Why did you accept this answer?